# What's the relation dimensions of a png file and the length of the base64 string it generates?

Tags: png, base64

I'm using .Net's ASHX handlers to open/parse images. 
In order to do that, I need to set the `img`'s `src` to something like `src='img.ashx?strBase=<wayTooLongStringForTheServerToHandle>'`.

The problem is (as I tried to point above)  that the base-64 string is often too large to be passed via GET. An average 800x600px image (about 12kb in size) generates a 16.6k characters long string, while the same image, with 25% of its area (400x300px) has a mere 15% reduction  in it's string (around 14.3k).

Is there a direct relation between the dimensions of a png file with the it's base-64-string length?

Answer (score 3):

No, there is only an indirect relation. A Base64 encoded file generates 4 bytes for every 3 bytes. However, the dimensions of a PNG do dot directly translate into file size for a few reasons.

- Different color depths.
- Possible Alpha channel.
- Compressions.

A PNG that uses 8-bit color depth will only require one byte for each pixel, but a PNG using 24-bit color depth will require 3 bytes, and if you add an Alpha channel, 4 bytes. Compressions will then reduce the file size, depending on how many repeated bytes there are and how hard the compressor looks for them. There could also be meta data in the PNG file, along with the headers.

You could pre-determine the length of the base64 encoded file before encoding base on the file size using this formula:

```
ceil(FILESIZE / 3) * 4
```

Comment: *Compression* surely is the most important factor here. See the OP's "... 800x600px image (about 12kb in size)"; uncompressed, this would be almost half a megabyte in 8 bits, and four times as much in RGBA.

Comment: But I didn't apply any kind of compression in the first place; Not any explicit one, at least. I created the image in Paint.Net, and didn't specify any kind of. Don't know whether they do under the hood... But when @Alexander mentioned compressions, I used tinyPNG's online service, and got an average 51% reduction (39% in the larger and 65% in the smaller);

Comment: @EricWu Most-likely there is some light-compression under the hood. Some programs can then take the data and compress it further.

Comment: The *only* storage format that PNG uses is "compressed". But there are different ways to compress data. Personally, I prefer `pngcrush`, as it is very reliable in squeezing the most out of it.